# How can I get child elements of DIV element from HTML String?

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have an HTML string in PHP, e.g:

```
<div class="my-class">
    <div id="el1">
        Some content...
    </div>
    <div id="el2">
        Some more content...
    </div>
    <div id="el3">
        Even more content...
    </div>
</div>
```

Over simplified but you get the idea. My real world data actually has 5 child elements with various classes and IDs assigned to them. Using just the class `my-class`, I need to extract the child elements from the string (either one by one or all at once) and into a new string, so I end up with:

```
    <div id="el1">
        Some content...
    </div>
    <div id="el2">
        Some more content...
    </div>
    <div id="el3">
        Even more content...
    </div>
```

I've tried using various DOMDocument and DOMXPath commands, mostly from different answers here on SO, but so far have been unable to achieve what I need. Unfortunately my experience with DOM in PHP is very limited. How can I get the elements from the string without the parent div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very straightforward solution (without DomDocument,e.t):

```
$str = '<div class="my-class"><div id="el1">....</div>';

$mask = '<div class="my-class">';
$str = str_replace($mask,'',$str);
$str = substr($str,0,strlen($str)-6);
echo $str;
```

Comment: Haha, I was overcomplicating it with DOMDocument. Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$str = '<div class="my-class"><div id="el1">....</div>';
$mask = '/(<div class="my-class">)|(</div>)/';
$str = preg_replace($mask,'',$str);
echo $str;
```